# How to find max value for each column using LINQ (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, linq, max, multiple-columns

I'm writing a code using LINQ (vb.net) to find max values for every column in data table. My data look like this: 
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
|     Date    | Value1  | Value2  | Value3  |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1/1/2013 |        12 |         13 |         19 | 
| 1/2/2013 |          9 |         20 |         17 | 
| 1/3/2013 |        17 |           5 |         10 | 
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+

I want to write a code to return single data record with max value in each column from all data rows so I can bind the result with gridview:

+----------+----------+----------+
|   Max1   |   Max2   |   Max3  |
+----------+----------+----------+
|         17 |         20 |         19 | 
+----------+----------+----------+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Max`:

```
Dim rows = table.AsEnumerable()
Dim Max1 = rows.Max(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("Value1"))
Dim Max2 = rows.Max(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("Value2"))
Dim Max3 = rows.Max(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("Value3"))
```

If these fields actually are strings (they should not), you have to use `Int32.Parse`.

If you need these values as datasource for the `GridView`, you can use a `DataTable` with one row:

```
Dim tblSource = New DataTable()
tblSource.Columns.Add("Max1", GetType(Int32))
tblSource.Columns.Add("Max2", GetType(Int32))
tblSource.Columns.Add("Max3", GetType(Int32))
tblSource.Rows.Add(Max1, Max2, Max3)
```

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, is there a way to put these results into IEnumerable Object or data row? I want to bind it with gridview. Also, I have to do the similar thing but with SUM function so I can add them as another row if I can put them into single record.

Comment: Schmeter: Oh! I can see it now! Thank you so much! :D